# JavaScript manually re-arrange rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Here is how I get the table:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
```

and here is only table rows without header and footer, basically table body only:

```
var tableBodyRowsONLY = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0).getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Here is the code to get a row and then insert it back into a table:

```
    var tempSaveRow;

    for (var x = 0; x < tableBodyRowsONLY.length ; x++) {          
        tempSaveRow = tableBodyRowsONLY[x].innerHTML;
        console.log(tableBodyRowsONLY[x]);
    }

    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    row.innerHTML = tempSaveRow;
```

Don't worry about the loop, it only takes the last row for now (work in progress still).

My problem is this when the row goes back into the table it is missing all css classes associated with that row. How can I fix that? Maybe a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) instead of `innerHTML`. That way you will also replace the row element itself, including all its attributes. In your current code, you only move the contents of the row to a new, empty row that doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of appendChild,insertBefore,replaceChild be better? That way you move the actual element and not have to worry about html,attributes,event listeners, or whatever else

Comment: @PatrickEvans Good point. And what you say is especially useful if you add data through JQuery or bind events. Usually I use jQuery.on for events nowadays, and then it doesn't matter, but you've got a fair point: this method will create a new element, which may be 'incomplete' somehow.